# Redirecting the page in RSpec to some other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I am using the Devise gem for authentication, also i have specified

```
before_filter :authenticate_contact!
```

in my `ApplicationController`. So user needs to `login` before accessing the application. If he by mistake types `url` without login, it will ask the user for authentication, once he logs in it will redirect to his given `url` instead of dashboard, i have used the following code for it

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    flash[:notice] = "Welcome #{current_contact.first_name} #{current_contact.last_name}, #{current_contact.company.genre}."
    session[:announcements] = true
    sign_in_url = new_contact_session_url
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
```

This is working fine. My next step was to write a RSpec spec:

In my spec/controller/application_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      sign_in_url = new_contact_session_url
      if request.referer == sign_in_url
        super
      else
        stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
      end
    end
  end

  before (:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:contact_owner, email: 'owner@test.com')
  end

  describe "After sigin-in" do
    it "redirects to the root path" do
      controller.after_sign_in_path_for(@user).should == root_path
    end
  end

end
```

This spec is getting passed and it is the first scenario, that is user comes to application logs in and get `root_path`. But I am facing difficulty in testing second condition that is if user types url without authentication, it will ask for the authentication and after login, it should redirect to his path instead of `root_path`.

```
describe CompaniesController do
    before do 
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:contact_owner, email: "test@test.com")
    end
    context "when logged in redirect to path" do
      before { sign_out @user }
      after { sign_in @user } #after this how can i proceed, here user is trying companies/index without login. once he logs in it should redirect_to(companies_path)
      it { get :index }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `before` and `after` blocks in RSpec are used to setup and tear down the example:

```
describe FooController do
  before { do_something } # runs before the nested describe
  describe "GET #index" do
    before { get :index } # runs after do_something
    after { clean_up } # runs after each example
    it "renders the correct template" do
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end 
  end
end
```

This is equivelent to the `setup` and `teardown` steps in TDD. The key takeaway here is that you cannot continue after the `after` block. It should not be used to structure examples, instead just to tear down any fixtures or anything which may linger such as session data or to reset a cache for example.

The `after` block is seldom used outside of your `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`. Use tools like [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) and [the test helpers for your auth system](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers) to provide a clean slate and you will almost never need to clean up after individual examples.

### Integration testing.

Controller specs are good for low level tests that give you a quick means to test how your controllers respond to different input. They use several abstractions for speed which means that they don't touch the whole stack such as routing and view rendering.

**For testing a authentication system you most likely will need an [feature spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) instead.**

The key difference is that a feature spec tests the application from the point of view of an actual user, you click your way around in the application and write expectations on the content that user is presented:

```
# spec/features/authentication_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature "Authentication" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  scenario "when a user attemps to access a resource that requires authentication" do
    visit some_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Please sign in'
  end

  scenario "when a user signs in with correct details" do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Sign In'
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign In'
    expect(page).to have_content "Welcome #{user.email}!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @max, will go through it